# split one column to multiple column and insert into another table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table like this

```
---table 1----------------------------------------------------------
string|
14, 123, A, 1000, 2017-09-10, h, 2, a 
 14, 789, C, 8000, 2017-11-02, m, 2, c
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i want to split this table column into 8 column and insert it table2 like this:

```
---table 2----------------------------------------------------------
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5       | col6 | col7 | col8
14     123    A      1000  2017-09-10     h      2       a
14     789    C      8000  2017-11-02     m      2       c
```

but i can't do it!

Comment: OK, that's great! You can probably achieve that.

Comment: Use conditional `CASE WHEN` logic or `PIVOT`. Need more to help. Surely you read SO posts longer than one line!

Comment: Do a search with the terms "string split sql server" and you'll find a bunch of results for your needs.

Comment: Try the split command, depending on your version of SQL.

Comment: my sql version is 2016. i can split this but after split the column show as row and i can't insert into table 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. It will work for you.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](    
    [col1] [varchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [col1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col4] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col5] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col6] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col7] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [col8] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO table1(col1) VALUES('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8')
INSERT INTO table1(col1) VALUES('10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80')

;WITH Split_Names (xmlcol)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    CONVERT(XML,'<ColName><name>'  
    + REPLACE(col1,',', '</name><name>') + '</name></ColName>') AS xmlcol
      FROM table1
)
INSERT INTO table2(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8)
 SELECT    
 xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[1]','varchar(100)') AS col1    
 ,xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[2]','varchar(100)') AS col2
 ,xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[3]','varchar(100)') AS col3
 ,xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[4]','varchar(100)') AS col4
 ,xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[5]','varchar(100)') AS col5
 ,xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[6]','varchar(100)') AS col6
 ,xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[7]','varchar(100)') AS col7
 ,xmlcol.value('/ColName[1]/name[8]','varchar(100)') AS col8
 FROM Split_Names
```

Comment: that's great! Thank you.